# Customise colors of graphs in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to customize colors of a ggplot. I have a plot of 11 timelines in one plot an now want to customize their colors.
At first i named the colors like that:

```
Colors_custom<-c("#000000","#00EEEE","#EEAD0E","#006400","#BDB76B","#EE7600","#68228B","#8B0000","#1E90FF","#EE6363","#556B2F")
```

Than I changed ggplot from

```
ggplot(timeline,aes(x=Year,y=value,color=Projection,group=Projection))+
geom_line(size=0.6) + xlab("Year") + ylab("Recharge [mm/a]") + 
ggtitle("Recharge") +  theme_bw() 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1961,1980,2000,2020,2040,2060,2080,2100)) + 
theme(axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold"), title=element_text(size=15,face="bold"))
```

to

```
ggplot(timeline,aes(x=Jahr,y=value,color=Colors_custom,group=Projection))+ ...
```

Result was warning

```
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:c("#000000", "#00EEEE", "#EEAD0E", "#006400", "#BDB76B", "#EE7600", "#68228B", "#8B0000", "#1E90FF", "#EE6363", "#556B2F")
```

i want to plot lines (out of points) so I took geom_line,
but that does not work as you can see.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your original code:

`scale_colour_manual(values = Colors_custom)`

It would be very helpful if you could supply your original data, as I am kind of shooting in the dark now.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i've been trying already with scale_fill_manual but didn't get to this. I must admit, i haven't heard of this special one yet. I'm just a beginner with R.