# How to establish specific colors in a barplot in ggplot R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am currently working on a dataframe and I want to make a barplot in which every cloumn is related to a variable, and I want to assign to each column (each bar of the barplot) an specific color, different than the predefined color assigned by `ggplot`.

This is my dataframe

```
    Abstencion    PP    PSOE    IU    UPyD   Ahora.madrid Ciudadanos Year
1      40.86     27.79  20.20  5.72   0.00         0.00       0.00  a91
2      28.87     37.35  19.62 11.02   0.00         0.00       0.00  a95
3      39.94     29.54  21.49  5.17   0.00         0.00       0.00  a99
4      31.07     35.21  25.18  4.95   0.00         0.00       0.00  a03
5      34.09     36.48  20.28  5.69   0.00         0.00       0.00  a07
6      32.78     32.79  15.79  7.09   5.18         0.00       0.00  a11
7      31.15     23.62  10.44  1.16   1.25        21.76       7.81  a15
```

The columns of the dataset are actually political parties in my country, so I want to produce a barplot depending on the year, in which each column should be plotted in the colour of the political party.

I already designed the color vector:

```
col <- c("black","dodgerblue","firebrick1","chartreuse3",
         "deeppink","darkorchid3","darkorange1")
```

And I developed this code to do the barplots (suppose my dataframe is X)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
a <- X[1,]
a.molten <- melt(a, value.name="Votes", variable.name="Party")
#Eliminar los partidos politicos que sacaron 0 votos
a.molten <- a.molten[-which(a.molten$Votes==0),] 
ggplot(a.molten, aes(x=Party, y=Votes, fill=Party)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

changing the parameter from  `a <- X[i,]` will produce the barplots for each year, but now I am stuck on assigning each party its color from the vector "col."

Comment: `?scale_colour_manual`, `?scale_fill_manual`

Comment: I feel like this must be answered somewhere on SO, but so far I have only found *related* questions - nothing that answers precisely this question, but several that show in passing how to use `scale_*_manual`.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099594/customise-colors-of-graphs-in-ggplot/20104120#20104120